# Ansible after update to 2.8 cannot find Python libraries

Tags: python, azure, ansible

Was running Ansible 2.7.9 and found that I needed a module that was in 2.8. Tried updating with pip but found that it wouldn't update, it said it did, but --version showed that it didn't. Ended up using brew and having it overwrite the links which fixed it.

```
ansible 2.8.4
config file = None
configured module search path = ['/Users/farroar/.ansible/plugins/modules', 
'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
ansible python module location = 
/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.8.4_1/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible
executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
python version = 3.7.4 (default, Jul  9 2019, 18:15:00) [Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)]
```

So, from what I can see it must have moved the pointer to the wrong module location. Specifically it is complaining about the 'msrest' library (azure work). If I run python3 and import that library, it is there. Not sure how to fix the pointing of items.

I'm on OSX.

Comment: Looks like I just need to change the 'ansible python module location'' to where it was pointing before, but I can't seem to find where that would go in the ansible.cfg file.

Comment: where do you encounter the problem - on your local host or on the remote host?

Comment: It's all local host. It is the directory that Ansible is look to for the python libraries. before it was /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible, but after updating it is /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.8.4_1/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible

Comment: I've tried to set this up in a virtualenv but having issues with that as well. Not sure if it is possible to just start from scratch... but if I could only have ansible look at the old directory I'd be all set

Comment: i think its looking for stuff in python2 environments? not python3?

Comment: @Nathan: if you are using virtualenv and it is still not working for you, something is broken on your end. under virtualenv, everything should work for you flowlessly.

Comment: Let's ignore virtualenv for now. It isn't the real culprit. The most important item is that  before I installed Ansible 2.8 it was pointing to the correct library location for Python3. After update to 2.8, it is now pointing to a Brew defined location. I just need to flip that back. It was pointing to /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible but it is now pointing to /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.8.4_1 etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue. I needed to run the postinstall procedure for python3 in brew, uninstall Ansible entirely and re-install. After that, it fixed where it was pointing to.